# set default controller or exclude something from the url zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

I red all things I was able to find about Zend_Controller_Router_Route but I wasn't able to find how can is set default controller or exclude something from the url, for example:

www.example.com/test/controler/action

how can I ignore "test"?

Now I always get "test" as default controller..

Thanks,
Ventsislav Angelov

Answer (score 3):

this can be done in the .htaccess of the /public subdir.

add another RewriteCond like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test* [OR]
```

this should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In your example url *'test'* would be the module if you are using default routes.

```
www.example.com/test/controler/action //module = test, controller = controler, action = action
```

you can specify defaults for all three of these in your application.ini by using these lines:

```
 resources.frontController.defaultcontrollername = 'index'
 resources.frontController.defaultaction = 'index'
 resources.frontController.defaultmodule = 'default'
```

another available setting you may be interested in:

```
resources.frontController.useDefaultControllerAlways = false
```

**[EDIT]**
If you really need to filter a string from a route/request. You could probably do that with a route, but I don't know routes well enough to help with that. Another option (aside from .htaccess) would be to test and redirect. Maybe something like:

```
public function preDispatch() {
       $request = $this->getRequest();
       if ($request->getController() = 'test' || $request->getAction() = 'test' || $request->getModule() = 'test' ) {
           $this->_redirect('url');
      }
    }
```

This could be put in each controller, but would likely work better as a plugin. Of course you could use a switch() instead of a nasty if() statement.

Hopefully one of the router gurus will wander by with a better solution.

Good Luck...

Comment: Thank you very much. But what if I just want to ignore "test" as a default. I don't want "test" to be controller or module or action